# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. After changing bundle id

Tags: ios, xcode, software-distribution, xcode-organizer, bundle-identifier

I've changed my app bundle id "com.mycompany.Appname" to "com.mycompany.appname", to be the same as the app subscribed to itunes connect.

But after changing the name in info.plist, when I try to validate in organizer I get the two following errors (Be aware of uppercases and lowercases):

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'XXXXXX.com.mycompany.**appname**' for key 'application-indetifier' in 'Payload/Appname.app/Appname' is not supported. This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle indetifier.

The executable at Payload/Appname.app/Appname in Payload/Appname.app has been signed with identifier 'com.mycompany.**appname**' which does not match the bundle identifier 'com.mycompany.**Appname**'.

Is like I've changed the bundle identifier but XCode still thinks that the app name is with uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and did the following two things:

Click on the project under `Project Navigator` in the left sidebar.

1. Go to Capabilities *for each target* and check that you don't have any issues there. Click on "fix issue" if you got one.
2. Check each target, ex. Sandbox, Production or extension target (like NotificationService) that you have the same `Build Settings --> Product Bundle Identifier` as in your corresponding Info.plist files, and `General --> Bundle Identifier`

Just took me a day of Googling and trying to find out. :P

Answer (score 0):

You must use the bundle id that of appID related to provisioning profile that you are using to sign the application. 
Try creating new appid with bundle identifier 'com.mycompany.appname'(exactly same as in the plist file- case sensitive) in dev portal and create new provisioning profile with that, then use that provisioning profile to sign your app.

Comment: I've tried it. The unique string that stills being called 'Appname' is the name of the project, which I think that wouldn't affect. Isn't it?

Comment: anything that you put in the plist and in appid must be same is case sensitive aso

Comment: OMG.. After 3 hours of madness, I've decided to reset the computer. I had tried to reset XCode, but not all entire computer. It have worked now.